How to change polling interval of ethers.js provider in hardhat
Default pollingInteval of ethersjs provider is too high (4 seconds) for my network and I want to change it to something like 1000ms. But when I try something like this:
import {ethers} from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const provider = ethers.provider;
  provider.pollingInterval = 1000;
  const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("ForwardZil");
  console.log("Deploying contract...");

I get this error:
Error: cannot set property _pollingInterval in read-only proxy
    at Object.set (/home/saeed/project/zilliqa/zq2/evm_scilla_js_tests/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/updatable-target-proxy.ts:89:13)
    at main (/home/saeed/project/zilliqa/zq2/evm_scilla_js_tests/scripts/Dep.ts:8:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/saeed/project/zilliqa/zq2/evm_scilla_js_tests/scripts/Dep.ts:33:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/saeed/project/zilliqa/zq2/evm_scilla_js_tests/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/saeed/project/zilliqa/zq2/evm_scilla_js_tests/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)

Although it's possible to change it in ethers.js, the hardhat wrapper around this library prevents me from setting it. I know I can use raw ethers.js in hardhat but I want to use the wrapper utilities and functions.

The docs say that hardhat takes a pollingInterval option: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/api-hardhat-upgrades#common-options.  What have you tried?

In Hardhat, the default ethers.provider is a read-only proxy, which prevents direct modification of properties like pollingInterval. However, you can create a custom provider using ethers.js directly while still taking advantage of Hardhat's utilities.
Here's the minimal script using Hardhat default network:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { ethers: rawEthers } = require("ethers");

async function main() {

    // Create a custom provider using ethers.js
    const customProvider = new rawEthers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:8545');

    // Set the polling interval to 1000ms
    customProvider.pollingInterval = 1000;

    // Get the list of available signers in Hardhat
    const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

    if (signers.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("No accounts found in the Hardhat network");
    }

    const signer = signers[0]

    // Connect the signer to the custom provider
    const customSigner = signer.connect(customProvider);

    const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test", customSigner);

    console.log("Deploying contract...");

    const deployedTx = await Contract.deploy()
    const deployed = await deployedTx.waitForDeployment();

    console.log('Deployed at: ', await deployed.getAddress())

}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});

P.S., However, as @ruby_newbie has mentioned in the comment, the newer versions of Hardhat support the pollingInterval parameter. You can refer to this GitHub issue for more details.

Error: cannot alter JSON-RPC Signer connection (operation="connect", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)

Which version of hardhat and ethers are you using?

"ethers": "^5.7.2",
"hardhat": "^2.18.0",

Can you try using "ethers": "^6.13.3" and "hardhat": "^2.22.12"?
